# ReplaceAll command /. (a possible bug?)

Tags: replacement

Suppose you have a list, with each element an ordered pair {a,b}
We want to create a new list where each element {a,b} is replaced by {a+b,a-b}

If the original list has three or more ordered pairs, the following works:

```
list1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}; (* This list has three ordered pairs *)

list1 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + y, x - y}
```

The output is, as expected:  `{{a + b, a - b}, {c + d, c - d}, {e + f, e - f}}`

However, if the list has ONLY TWO ordered pairs, the above procedure doesn't seem to work, as shown below:

```
list2 = {{a, b}, {c, d}}; (* This list has ONLY TWO ordered pairs *)

list2 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + y, x - y}
```

The output is, unexpectedly(?)  `{{a + c, b + d}, {a - c, b - d}}`
Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work?  I would appreciate any insight.

I know I can do something like the following to get the desired result:

```
Cases[list2, {x_, y_} -> {x + y, x - y}]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not a bug.
Use `Replace[list1, {x_, y_} -> {x + y, x - y}, {1}]` for what you're after.

Comment: if you _have to_ use `ReplaceAll`, try `list2 /. {Except[_List, x_], y_} :> {x + y, x - y}`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.  I understand it now!

Answer (score 5):

[`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) scans the expression starting with the outermost level, working its way inwards.

Therefore, in your example, `x_` will match `{a,b}` and `y_` will match `{c,d}`.

This is an extremely common mistake, and it is why I never use `ReplaceAll` to process a list of elements. Use Replace instead, and indicate that it should only work at level `{1}`, i.e. process the elements of the list one-by-one.

```
Replace[list1, {x_, y_} -> {x + y, x - y}, {1}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.  I understand it now!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it:

```
x = π;
list1 = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {e, f}}; (* non-rectangular array *)
list2 = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
list3 = {{a, b}};
list4 = {a, b};

list1 /. {x_, y_}?VectorQ :> {x + y, x - y}
list2 /. {x_, y_}?VectorQ :> {x + y, x - y}
list3 /. {x_, y_}?VectorQ :> {x + y, x - y}
list4 /. {x_, y_}?VectorQ :> {x + y, x - y}
```

Note the use of `:>` instead of `->` is required, since `x` has a value.