# Deleting elements from the nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a nested list:

```
 {{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {28.9063, 0.861155}}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, {32.2188, 0.512393}}, {{1, 1, 1, 21}, {29.9063, 0.410614}}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, {27.4219, 0.351969}}}
```

and I would like to delete these elements 28.9063, 32.2188, 29.9063, 27.4219. Final list should look like this:

```
{{{1, 1, 1, 1},  0.861155}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, 0.512393}, {{1, 1, 1, 21}, 0.410614}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, 0.351969}}
```

Is there in Mathematica quick way to do it without a lot of cycles?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) to replace the two-element lists on level 2 with their second entry:

```
list = {{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {28.9063, 0.861155}}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, {32.2188, 0.512393}}, {{1, 1, 1, 21}, {29.9063, 0.410614}}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, {27.4219, 0.351969}}};
Replace[list, {_, x_} :> x, {2}]
(* {{{1, 1, 1, 1},  0.861155}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, 0.512393}, {{1, 1, 1, 21}, 0.410614}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, 0.351969}} *)
```

Alternatively, you can use assignments to [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)s of the expression:

```
res = list;
res[[All, 2]] = res[[All, 2, 2]];
res
(* {{{1, 1, 1, 1}, 0.861155}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, 0.512393}, {{1, 1, 1, 21}, 0.410614}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, 0.351969}} *)
```

Note that we copy the list first to avoid modifying the original. Based on quick tests, this is ~20x faster on my machine than the first solution

Answer (score 7):

```
alist = {{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {28.9063, 0.861155}}, {{1, 1, 1, 
    11}, {32.2188, 0.512393}}, {{1, 1, 1, 21}, {29.9063, 
    0.410614}}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, {27.4219, 0.351969}}}
```

Using replacement and without overwriting the original list:

```
alist /. {a_Real, b_Real} :> b
```

---

**EDIT**

Using `SequenceReplace`:

```
SequenceReplace[alist,
 {{a_List, {b_Real, c_Real}}} :> {a, c}
 ]
```

The `Sequence*` functions are not known for their performance but these are quite flexible.

---

Result:

> {{{1, 1, 1, 1}, 0.861155}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, 0.512393}, {{1, 1, 1, 21},
> 0.410614}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, 0.351969}}

Comment: (+1) Using `SequenceReplace`.

Comment: (+1) To make a general pedantic point (which does _not_ directly apply here), `ReplaceAll` " looks at each part of expr, tries all the rules on it, and then goes on to the next part of expr" and "The first rule that applies to a particular part is used; no further rules are tried on that part or on any of its subparts". `ReplaceAll` tries all parts of expr from the outside in, _including_ the `Head`, (including in the OP example) and this can cause problems if the pattern happens to match 'Head'.

Comment: Since [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236391/106) by szabolcs I have personally stopped using `ReplaceAll` in favour of `Replace` as I have been badly 'bitten' in the past.  See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188608/106) by Lucas Lang

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, though slower, makes use of the new function `DeleteElements` from v13.1

It is handy if you

1. Want to preserve the dimensions of the original list (`list`)
2. Delete specific elements which may or may not repeat
3. Elements to delete are not in order

```
list={{{1,1,1,1},{28.9063,0.861155}},{{1,1,1,11},{32.2188,0.512393}},{{1,1,1,21},{29.9063,0.410614}},{{1,1,1,31},{27.4219,0.351969}}};

finalList={{{1,1,1,1},0.861155},{{1,1,1,11},0.512393},{{1,1,1,21},0.410614},{{1,1,1,31},0.351969}};

delete={28.9063,32.2188,29.9063,27.4219}; (* or list[[All,2,1]] *)


deletedList=Map[DeleteElements[#,delete]&,list,2]; (* {{{1,1,1,1},{0.861155`}},{{1,1,1,11},{0.512393`}},{{1,1,1,21},{0.410614`}},{{1,1,1,31},{0.351969`}}} *)
deletedList === finalList (* False*)
```

To get your desired output you can adjust the output

```
gar = Transpose@deletedList;
bar = Flatten[#[[-1]]] &@gar;
adjustedList = Transpose[{gar[[1]], bar}]; (*{{{1,1,1,1},0.861155},{{1,1,1,11},0.512393},{{1,1,1,21},0.410614},{{1,1,1,31},0.351969}}*)

adjustedList === finalList  (* True*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just another way, using `Cases`, `DeleteElements` and `Function`:

```
Map[Function[{y}, Join[DeleteElements[y, {_, x_} :> x], Cases[y, {_, x_} :> x]]], list]
(*{{{1, 1, 1, 1}, 0.861155}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, 0.512393}, {{1, 1, 1, 21}, 0.410614}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, 0.351969}}*)
```

Or using `MapAt`:

```
Transpose@MapAt[#[[All, 2]] &, Transpose@list, {2}]
(*{{{1, 1, 1, 1}, 0.861155}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, 0.512393}, {{1, 1, 1, 21}, 0.410614}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, 0.351969}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Cases`:

```
Cases[list, {{x__},{y_,z_}}:> {{x},z}]


(*  {{{1, 1, 1, 1}, 0.861155}, {{1, 1, 1, 11}, 0.512393}, 
     {{1, 1, 1, 21}, 0.410614}, {{1, 1, 1, 31}, 0.351969}} *)
```

Alternatively:

```
Cases[list, {x_List,{y_,z_}}:> {x,z}]
```