# How can I get rid of the parenthesis in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am new in mathematica , I am trying to solve an equation and show a graph of the solution and I am getting empty graph because of the additional Parenthesis I get .
for example I want to get `{101.,0.26994}` but I am getting `{101., {0.26994}}`

Please see my code below

```
c = -55.26*0.05;
k = 9.04788;
Bs = 120;
μ = 0.015504;

energy =
 
 Table[{b, λ /. 
    NSolve[{(c λ)/(c λ - 1) - k/c (c λ)^2 + 
        c^2 (μ (b - Bs)) == 0, λ >= 0},
     Reals]}, {b, 101, Bs, 0.2}]

ListPlot[{energy},
 Frame -> True,
 Joined -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Check document of `Part`, `First`.

Comment: @user1066 you suggested a nice answer that is different from the proposed solutions. May I suggest that you write it as an answer rather than a comment? I am happy to upvote it :-)

Comment: This question is answered in this article of the "Pitfalls" Q&A: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListPlot[ArrayReshape[energy, {Length@energy, 2}], Frame -> True, 
 Joined -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: Thank you alot !

Comment: @maya glad I was able to help :-)

Answer (score 6):

The $X$ problem in this $XY$ question is answered here: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706)

The $Y$ problem in this $XY$ question:

> I am new in mathematica , I am trying to solve an equation and show a graph

*Solving the equation:*

Adapted from one of the methods in [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706)
:

```
fn = Normal@
  First@SolveValues[{(c \[Lambda])/(c \[Lambda] - 1) - 
       k/c (c \[Lambda])^2 + c^2 (\[Mu] (b - Bs)) == 0, 
     101 <= b <= Bs}, \[Lambda], Reals]
```

> SolveValues::ratnz: SolveValues was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.
>
> ```
> (*
> Root[-8.43611*10^47 + 
>    7.03009*10^45 b + (-2.16679*10^48 + 1.94241*10^46 b) #1 + 
>    1.48485*10^48 #1^2 + 4.10264*10^48 #1^3 &, 1]
> *)
> ```

Many users are irritated by the warning message. It's not an error, just an explanation of a step `Solve` took.  The reasons the system is programmed to warn the user in this situation are: (1) `Solve` is an "exact" solver and produces exact output but only if the input is exact; floating-point numbers are treated as inexact. And (2) using exact methods on inexact input might lead to numerical instability (excessive round-off error).

To get rid of the warning, you can use `Quiet[Solve[...]]` or explictly do what `Solve` says it is doing:

```
fn = (*N[*) (* numericizing the result is optional, imo *)
  Normal@First@SolveValues[
    Rationalize[
     {(c \[Lambda])/(c \[Lambda] - 1) - k/c (c \[Lambda])^2 + 
        c^2 (\[Mu] (b - Bs)) == 0, 101 <= b <= Bs},
     0],
    \[Lambda], Reals]
  (*]*)
```

> ```
> (*
> Root[-5506087503309720000 + 
>    45884062527581000 b + (-14142202016653037763 + 
>       126777664763706303 b) #1 + 9691344913034469000 #1^2 + 
>    26777185994714237847 #1^3 &, 1]
> *)
> ```

*Plotting the graph:*

```
Plot[fn, {b, 101, Bs}, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

> [image]

To plot the graph without solving the equation (perhaps the true $Y$ question):

```
ContourPlot[
 {(c \[Lambda])/(c \[Lambda] - 1) - k/c (c \[Lambda])^2 + 
    c^2 (\[Mu] (b - Bs)) == 0},
 {b, 101, Bs}, {\[Lambda], 0, 0.29}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to achieve your goal, e.g.

```
energy = Table[{b}~Join~
   (\[Lambda] /. 
     NSolve[{(c \[Lambda])/(c \[Lambda] - 1) - k/c (c \[Lambda])^2 + 
         c^2 (\[Mu] (b - Bs)) == 0, \[Lambda] >= 0}, Reals]),
 {b, 101, Bs, 0.2}]
```

[image]

you can also try `Flatten` to cope with extra curly brakets (namely, braces).

Comment: (+1) that's also very nice!

Answer (score 5):

(1)

*One* way to get a list of *{ {x,y}, ... }* values suitable for `ListPlot` is to  [Splice](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Splice.html) the list produced by `ReplaceAll` into the surrounding list, thereby avoiding the problem of the extra set of braces in the first place:

```
etwo= Table[{b, Splice[λ /. 
    NSolve[{(c λ)/(c λ - 1) - k/c (c λ)^2 + 
        c^2 (μ (b - Bs)) == 0, λ >= 0},
     Reals]]}, {b, 101, Bs, 0.2}]

Short[etwo]

(*  {{101., 0.26994}, {101.2, 0.268292}, <<93>>, {120., 0.}} *)
```

(2)

```
ListPlot[etwo, Frame -> True, Joined -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

(3)

```
Short[energy]

{{101., {0.26994}}, {101.2, {0.268292}}, <<93>>, {120., {0.}}}
```

There are many ways to convert the list `energy` into a list of *{ {x,y}, ...}* values (ie convert `energy` to `etwo`), including:

```
Flatten/@energy==etwo
Delete[#,{2,0}]&/@energy==etwo  (* delete the Head *)
Replace[energy, {x_,{y_}}-> {x,y},{1}] ==etwo 

( *  True
     True
     True *)
```

[ReplaceAll](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) may also be used, but is [risky](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/236391/106) with pattern matching and IMO is best avoided.

(4) **Delete vs Flatten**

Compare:

```
expt={{a1, {b1},{c1}},{a2,{b2},{c2}}}
Flatten/@expt
Delete[#,{2,0}]&/@expt

{{a1, {b1}, {c1}}, {a2, {b2}, {c2}}}
{{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}}
{{a1, b1, {c1}}, {a2, b2, {c2}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your equation can be solved exactly.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use exact input

```
c = -5526/100*5/100;
k = 904788*^-5;
Bs = 120;
μ = 15504*^-6;

sol = SolveValues[{(c λ)/(c λ - 1) - k/c (c λ)^2 + 
      c^2 (μ (b - Bs)) == 0, λ >= 0}, λ, Reals][[1]]
```

[image]

The exact solution is a [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) containing a [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expression.

You can use [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) to convert this `Root` expression to an explicit form

```
sol // ToRadicals // Simplify
```

[image]

Clearly, the `Root` expression is a more compact representation.

Plotting,

```
Plot[sol, {b, 37, Bs}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely done. I did not even check for an exact solution....(sighs) :/